# Cannot find the declaration of element doctrine-mongo-mapping

Tags: php, eclipse, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to debug a website written with Symfony 2 using Eclipse Mars. After solving the Composer dependencies (the ones from composer.json), and setting up the database, I cannot get past this error, and I could not find any clue on the web. Any suggestion?

[image]

**UPDATE**: I ran another Composer update, cleaned and built and now I have four instances of the same error:

```
White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
```

Each instance of the error matches a doctrine xml: Group.mongodb.xml, User.mongodb.xml, Group.orm.xml, User.orm.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute, switching the two URLs solved it (the one ending in .xsd goes first)